# OG Meta Tags not being scraped by facebook or twitter

Tags: tags, facebook, meta-value

When trying to share a blog from my wordpress website on social media, (facebook, twitter), there is no URL preview card. No picture, no description, nothing. I installed yoast seo plugin on my wordpress website, and I can see in the source code that there is meta tags placed. I've even compared my source code to other sites who have their url card working and it's the exact same. The facebook debugger doesn't even recognize or show that the meta tags are there.

I've installed multiple meta tag plugins trying everything, and to no avail.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Pop your website into the facebook debugger.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

This will do 2 things:

1. Flush the cached version of your site Facebook has stored.
2. Tell you any problems with sharing data that may prevent those OG tags being used.

In the event of no errors and cache refreshed, you can then share your link again and it should have the OG tagged elements included in your shared snippet.

The twitter version can also be found here:
https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator